# Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(firebase_core, Can't create handler inside thread Thread that has not called Looper.prepare(), null, null)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-in-app-messaging

I am using:

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
 
  runApp(...);
}
```

On running the app on Android, I get the following error:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(firebase_core, Can't create handler inside thread Thread[pool-3-thread-1,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare(), null, null)

I'm using `firebase_in_app_messaging: ^0.6.0+6`. The above code works on removing this package.

If I remove `await` keyword, the code runs successfully, but is this a bug or am I doing it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

What if you add **Future< void>** ?

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
runApp(...); ,}
```

Comment: Sorry, it won't help.